# Owing to be or owing to being?

Tags: grammar

I fought with one tutor about grammar because 
I said:

> She is intelligent owing to being teacher

She said:

> She is intelligent owing to be teacher

Or are both of us mistaken?

Comment: Neither of you is correct. You seem to be trying to say 'She is intelligent, owing to her being a teacher' (which isn't very logical!)

Comment: As an English learner, keep it simple. And continue to keep it simple when you are no longer a learner, unless absolutely necessary. The English is "because she is". Simple, familiar two-syllable "because" instead of contorted two word "owing to", and present tense instead of some other more complex tense that you don't know how to use. See SE English Languge Learners if you want to find out how. As a native English speaker I would never use "owning to" instead of "because" in this sort of situation (or ever, as far as I can see).

Comment: …And she is a teacher because she is intelligent, I imagine, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence would be:

> She is intelligent owing to her being a teacher.

Here "being" is a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund). It would be simpler to say, "She is intelligent because she is a teacher." However, becoming a teacher does not cause someone to become intelligent, so neither of these sentences really make sense, despite being grammatical.